# How can I return Home activity from child activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

This is my code, I want to go to Home activity by clicking app    icon     button. My same code works fine for HomeActivity   button .

```
package com.coderbd.englishtutor;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class StudyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button app_icon_topBar;
ImageButton reset;
ImageButton settings;
ImageButton share;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_study);
    app_icon_topBar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.app_icon_topBar);
    reset=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_Reset);
    settings=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_Settings);
    share=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_Share);

    app_icon_topBar.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
    settings.setOnClickListener(this);
    share.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.app_icon_topBar:
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.another_home_activity);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_Reset:
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_Settings:
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_Share:
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores);
        break;
    default:
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.another_home_activity);
        break;  
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: I did not use Action bar and I have removed from style and my theme is without action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your app icon button's onClick:

```
case R.id.app_icon_topBar:
    Intent intent = new Intent(StudyActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

Comment: Can you explain me what happens when you run my code? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Hi Icon Button does not respond at all.

Comment: your other buttons does? can you show me your layout XML file?

Comment: Hi There is 6 buttons on my HomeActivity, and I have used same code for those 6 buttons, those work fine for me, and I can go another activity clicking those button. But I have used same code at StudyActivity, But button does not work at all, No respond at all. Here is XML file: http://onlinetotalsolutions.com/activity_study.xml

Comment: remove android:launchMode="singleTop" from the manifest at StudyActivity

Comment: I have removed, but no response from icon button.